# PyPy Sandbox: Cannot import rpython module

Tags: python, sandbox, pypy

I'm trying to use PyPy to create a server-side sandbox with limited access to my file system. I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit machine and have been trying to install the full source code for PyPy from here: http://pypy.org/download.html#sandboxed-version (scroll down to the section "Building from source").

My problem is that whenever I try running pypy_interact.py (located in pypy/pypy/sandbox), I get the following error:

ImportError: No module named rpython.translator.sandbox.sandlib

The module that cannot be imported has the following path: pypy/rpython/translator/sandbox/sandlib.py. The contents of pypy_interact.py are as follows:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..\
', '..', '..')))
from rpython.translator.sandbox.sandlib import SimpleIOSandboxedProc
from rpython.translator.sandbox.sandlib import VirtualizedSandboxedProc
from rpython.translator.sandbox.vfs import Dir, RealDir, RealFile
import pypy
LIB_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(pypy.__file__))
```

I feel like this is a really simple fix -- I just started learning Python a few days ago so I'm not exactly sure how to go about fixing the issue/don't understand imports too well yet. Any advice? Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe accept my answer then? :)

Answer (score 5):

Rpython typically expects that you set `PYTHONPATH` to include the root of your pypy checkout and not mess with the `sys.path`.

So you typically call the script via

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path/to/pypy/source path/to/pypy_interact.py
```